# Why is the center of 'percussion' called so?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, terminology, harmonic-oscillator, rigid-body-dynamics

I came across this word [Center of Percussion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_percussion) while reading **SHM** from **Resnick Halliday Krane Vol. 1** and couldn't figure out why it is called so. Please help me in doing so.

Answer (score -1):

Given an extended rigid body and a pivot point, the centre of percussion is the place at which a brief impact or blow causes no net force or acceleration at the pivot (because translational and rotational accelerations cancel out at the pivot).

A “[percussion](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/percussion)” is the sound made when two objects collide, hence “centre of percussion”.

Comment: The answer  by @gandalf61 is correct and complete, but it's worth understanding the applications to sports. When you hit a fast ball with a bat, and the ball strikes at the center of percussion you feel no jarring impact  to the hand(s) holding the bat and it feels like a "good hit".  If a fast  ball hits the bat away from the center of percussion then it can hurt, and because you hand(s) get deflected, you have less control over where the struck ball goes.

Comment: "percussion" is not a sound; it is the act of striking, whether or not a sound is produced.

Comment: @sammygerbil Thanks